# Read value of dynamically-selected property, e.g. (ListItem.Value/.Text)

Tags: vb.net, system.reflection

I have seen lots of *seemingly* related questions on SO, but my understanding of Reflection isn't sufficient enough to apply those to my case.

I have a method that sorts ListControl.ListItems by either Text or Value.  Rather than sort alphanumerically, the objects must be cast as Doubles, and then sorted, e.g.

```
<asp:ListItem Value="1.1" Text="1.1" />
<asp:ListItem Value="3.4" Text="3.4" />
<asp:ListItem Value="10.587" Text="10.587" />
```

My entire approach may be wrong, but my method first checks to see if any objects are not numeric.  If a potential error is found (non-parseable value)  then the method falls back to alphanumeric sorting:

```
Public Enum SortBy
    Value
    Text
End Enum

Public Shared Sub SortListItemsNumerically(lc As ListControl, sortby As SortBy)
    Dim parseFail As Boolean = False
    Select Case sortby
        Case SortBy.Value
            If (From li As ListItem In lc.Items
                Where Not IsNumeric(li.Value)
                Select li).ToArray().Count > 0 Then
                parseFail = True
            End If
        Case SortBy.Text
            If (From li As ListItem In lc.Items
                Where Not IsNumeric(li.Text)
                Select li).ToArray().Count > 0 Then
                parseFail = True
            End If
    End Select
    If parseFail Then
        ' ... fall back
    End If
    ' ... do sort 
End Sub
```

My issue is that there is repetitive code in the `Case` block.  Is it possible to *dynamically/smartly* check for a non-parseable value, to avoid that duplication of code?  Something such as:

```
Dim SomeMagicHere = li.Value/Text
If (From li As ListItem In lc.Items
     Where Not IsNumeric(SomeMagicHere)
     Select li).ToArray().Count > 0 Then
     parseFail = True
End If
```

Comment: Have you considered using 2 different methods rather than passing a "Mode" parameter?

Comment: Yes that's the approach I'm trying to get away from, as there's far too much repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a quick thing here. `GetProperty` and `GetValue` are the reflection methods:

```
If (From li As ListItem In lc.Items
    Where Not IsNumeric(li.GetType().GetProperty(sortby.ToString()).GetValue(li))
    Select li).ToArray().Count > 0 Then
    parseFail = True
End If
```

Comment: I've tested this code and I can get both Text/Value using `sortby` and the correct property and value is returned using reflection. Split the statement out into multiple variables so you can inspect each step.

Comment: Right.. I'm an idiot. I updated the code. I extracted the value into a variable from `lc` instead of instead the linq from `li` so obviously it was never going to get the right value. Derp.

Comment: That's working now, thank you.  Can you please explain why you used `GetValue(li, Nothing)` rather than just `GetValue(li)`?  Doesn't linq return each individual `li` for `GetValue` to read, negating the need for an index  (which you've set as Nothing anyway)?  Thanks

Comment: Hi, when I was quickly writing this up, this was the first thing that came up on intellisense. I didn't realise til now that the second parameter wasn't required, I'll edit it out